Can't push from local main to GitLab main (pre-receive hook declined)
I created my GitLab account about a month ago. Create my SSH keys, uploaded them and was using repositories without any problems. Had webhook integrations and deploy keys, no problems too.
Yesterday, I created a new repository, followed the instructions to push my local files to GitLab, as I did every other time and it failed with that message (main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)). I thought that was a problem in my local files or even for some obscure reason I might had created the repository wrong. Deleted and created again. Same error. Then I checked my other repositories and they had the same problem now, which they didn't had the last time I made a push from local to GitLab.
Decided to start with a clean folder on local, connected to my new repository and it worked.  Copied my files from original folder to new clean folder, added, commit and push and it worked. But my existing repositories which are already in use are having the same problem when I try to push.
What is happening? Every repository I created was with the default blank project settings and I didn't change anything on them. I didn't protect them either. It was all the default creation options.
Every search about this problem came up with either needing permissions, but I'm the owner or I need to unprotect the branch, but I didn't protect any branches on any repository and all were working fine until now. I have no idea what had been changed and for sure I didn't change any configurations.
I have two questions: What is causing this and how can I fix it?
